# For rows with duplicate keys, how do I get longest record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Given the following table, lacking any unique key, how can I group by id and get the Permissions column with the longest length?

SampleTable:

```
id | Permissions
------------------------------------
1  | Walk, Swim
1  | Walk, Sit, Swim, Run, Jump, Lay
1  | !Walk, Sit, Lay
2  | Walk, Sit, Swim
3  | !Walk, Sit, Swim
3  | Walk, Sit, Swim
```

I tried:

```
SELECT r.id, r.Permissions
FROM SampleTable AS r
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 u.id, u.Permissions
    FROM SampleTable AS u
    GROUP BY u.id, u.Permissions
    HAVING u.id = r.id
    ORDER BY MAX(LEN(Permissions)) DESC
) AS u
```

However I didn't get the correct results.

I'm looking for results like:

```
id | Permissions
-----------------------------------
1 | Walk, Sit, Swim, Run, Jump, Lay
2 | Walk, Sit, Swim
3 | !Walk, Sit, Swim
```

Edit:
This has already been answered, thanks. But as an aside, I should have had my SQL as:

```
SELECT r.id, u.Permissions
FROM SampleTable AS r
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 u.id, u.Permissions
    FROM SampleTable AS u
    WHERE u.id = r.id
    ORDER BY LEN(Permissions) DESC
) AS u
GROUP BY r.id, u.Permissions
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: You _really_ should move the `Permissions` to a table that you `JOIN` to your `SampleTable` so that you don't have to parse all the string information. That's the whole point of RDBMS.

Comment: Take a second to think WHY this table does not have unique keys.   Sometime (soon) you'll want to select one specific row - how are you going to pick it?    If you haven't heard of Third-Normal-Form before, take some time to read about it because your one table is contrary to 3NF in multiple ways !  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126588/understanding-3nf-plain-english-please

Comment: I didn't design the tables and I personally place auto-increment keys even on many-to-many relational tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use row_number() over().  such like:

```
with cte as (
    Select id, Permissions
    row_number() over( partition by id order by LEN(Permissions) desc) as rnum
    from SampleTable
) Select id, Permissions from cte where rnum = 1
```

Comment: This would 'drop' duplicates `(3, '!Walk, Sit, Swim');` `(3, '!Walk, Run, Swim');`

Comment: I agree, however that's what is his design entails.  his expected output is what I went with.  One Permissions list per id.  What I don't know is how to determine who came last or who is right in the list of duplicates?  like latest setting.  I am more inclined to agree with the commenters up top saying the design needs looking at than I am to recommend either of our solutions anyways.  Yours is better quality SQL irregardless.

Answer (score 0):

This literally is a *'who has the longest?'* contest!

You could try this the following which is more fair then partitioning since it will return all candidates with max length.

---

```
SELECT p2.id, p2.permissions
FROM table1 p2
JOIN (SELECT p.id, MAX(LEN(p.permissions)) AS longest FROM table1 p GROUP BY p.id) 
p1 ON p1.id = p2.id
AND p1.longest = Len(p2.permissions)
```

### Test

```
--drop table if exists table1
create table table1 ( id int, permissions nvarchar(100));

insert into table1 values(1, 'Walk, Swim');
insert into table1 values(1, 'Walk, Sit, Swim, Run, Jump, Lay');
insert into table1 values(1, '!Walk, Sit, Lay');
insert into table1 values(2, 'Walk, Sit, Swim');
insert into table1 values(3, '!Walk, Sit, Swim');
insert into table1 values(3, 'Walk, Sit, Swim');

SELECT p2.id, p2.permissions
FROM table1 p2
JOIN (SELECT p.id, MAX(LEN(p.permissions)) AS longest FROM table1 p GROUP BY p.id) 
p1 ON p1.id = p2.id
AND p1.longest = Len(p2.permissions)
```

### Output

```
id  permissions
1   Walk, Sit, Swim, Run, Jump, Lay
2   Walk, Sit, Swim
3   !Walk, Sit, Swim
```

---

## Multiple 'longests'

```
(...)
insert into table1 values(1, 'Walk, Swim');
insert into table1 values(1, 'Walk, Sit, Swim, Run, Jump, Lay');
insert into table1 values(1, '!Walk, Sit, Lay');
insert into table1 values(2, 'Walk, Sit, Swim');
insert into table1 values(3, '!Walk, Sit, Swim');
insert into table1 values(3, 'Walk, Sit, Swim');
insert into table1 values(3, '!Walk, Run, Swim'); -- extra record
```

Output:

```
id  permissions
1   Walk, Sit, Swim, Run, Jump, Lay
2   Walk, Sit, Swim
3   !Walk, Sit, Swim
3   !Walk, Run, Swim
```

Comment: There's a lot of scenarios where this information is useful.


In my case, I'm trying to trim bad data down to a unique id. Then fix any incorrect permissions later.